# g++ 4.7 bug with SFINAE + decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, sfinae

I have constructed the following MCVE to illustrate the issue I'm having with g++ 4.7.  It uses SFINAE via `decltype()` to determine if a functor type can be called with the given argument type (specialized to test if the functor type can be called with no arguments when the argument type is `void`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename F, typename A>
class can_call_functor_impl
{
private:
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename U>
    static auto test(U *)
        -> decltype(void(std::declval<U const &>()(std::declval<A &>())),
                    std::declval<yes &>());

    template <typename>
    static no & test(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<F>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename F>
class can_call_functor_impl<F, void>
{
private:
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename U>
    static auto test(U *)
        -> decltype(void(std::declval<U const &>()()),
                    std::declval<yes &>());

    template <typename>
    static no & test(...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test<F>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename F, typename A>
class can_call_functor :
    public std::integral_constant<bool, can_call_functor_impl<F, A>::value> {};

class int_functor
{
public:
    void operator()(int) const;
};

#define PRINT_EXP(e) (std::cout << #e " == " << (e) << std::endl)

int main(void) {
    PRINT_EXP((can_call_functor<int_functor, int>::value));
    PRINT_EXP((can_call_functor<int_functor, short>::value));
    PRINT_EXP((can_call_functor<int_functor, void>::value));
    PRINT_EXP((can_call_functor<int_functor, double>::value));
    PRINT_EXP((can_call_functor<int_functor, int_functor>::value));
}
```

Output on g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2:

```
(can_call_functor<int_functor, int>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, short>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, void>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, double>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, int_functor>::value) == 1
```

This output is troubling, as I would expect the third and fifth lines to have a result of 0, and indeed [later g++ and clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e97d01ab43d13641) are in agreement that this should be the case.

It appears that g++ 4.7 evaluates `can_call_functor<int_functor, T>::value` as true for any `T` I can come up with.

I strongly suspect this is a g++ bug specific to 4.7, but I can't find any evidence of this (these kinds of problems being particularly difficult to search for on bug trackers), so I'm looking for a definitive answer:

Is this a g++ 4.7 bug, and if so is there a workaround?  If it's not a bug in g++ then where is the bug in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a g++ 4.7 bug?

it appears to be

on 4.9.1 it produced

```
(can_call_functor<int_functor, int>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, short>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, void>::value) == 0
(can_call_functor<int_functor, double>::value) == 1
(can_call_functor<int_functor, int_functor>::value) == 0
```

> but I can't find any evidence of this (these kinds of problems being particularly difficult to search for on bug trackers)

this one might be the bug `https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53788`

> and if so is there a workaround?

ummm....

I cannot think any good one

move to at least 4.8? You could have several gcc installed side-by-side